# How to know the JVM path in a Linux system?

Tags: linux, java

I want to copy some files in the subdirectories of the JVM path , java is already installed. How to know the JVM's path ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
locate java
```

This will give you the location of java installation in your system.

Most probably it would be:

```
/usr/lib/java/
```

Answer (score 12):

Check your $JAVA_HOME environment variable from a terminal:

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
```

Comment: This is what I am trying to set using the located path :)

Answer (score 11):

In Linux you can use the `whereis` and `which` shell commands:

```bash
$ which java
$ whereis java
```

which will give you, most likely, the JRE path in `/usr/bin` folder such as `/usr/bin/java`.

This is not the actual JRE file, but a symbolic link to the actual JRE file (which is located elsewhere). To get the actual JRE path you have to follow that link

```bash
$ readlink -f /usr/bin/java
```

or whatever was the path of JRE returned by `which`/`whereis` command.

Comment: This is the only thing that works.

Answer (score -2):

```
which java
```

This is the simplest command and gives the exact path.

Comment: This answer is not correct because it shows the path of the `java` binary, which will most likely be `/usr/bin/java` or something of that sort, which is different from the actual path of the JRE.